# How to insert value into MySql table from user input JTextField

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I've tried to insert value into a table from user input in JTextField. The code runs with an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks!

Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class InputRoute
{

JTextField text1;
JTextField text2;
JTextField text3;
String c;
Float d;

public void inputRoute() 
{

    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "YarraTram";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "abc123";

    try 
    {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  ('route', 'price') VALUES ('"+c+"', '"+d+"')");
        statement.executeQuery();

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public void createAndShowGUI() 
{

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Yarra Tram Route Finder(New Route)");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("From: ");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("To: ");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Price: ");

    text1 = new JTextField(20);
    text2 = new JTextField(20);
    text3 = new JTextField(20);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Add");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Close");

    frame.add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(text1, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(label2, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(text2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(label3, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(text3, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);

    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            String a = text1.getText();
            String b = text2.getText();
            d = Float.parseFloat(text3.getText());

            c = a + " - " + b;

            inputRoute();
        }
    });
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });

    frame.setSize( 500,120 );
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
} 
}
```

Here is my MySQL table

```
 CREATE TABLE `route` (
 `rid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `route` varchar(100) ,
 `price` decimal(5,2) ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rid`)
 )
```

Comment: you could have searched this problem on google easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are missing the table name in:

```
... ("INSERT INTO  ('route', 'price') VALUES ...
                 /\
                  here
```

second, you shouldn't use the colons `'` with columns' names. Use the backtick instead like so:

```
... ("INSERT INTO  `route` (`route`, `price`) VALUES ...
```

The colons are used to pass literal values.

Comment: why we need > ' ' < this apostrophe in quary ? @MahmoudGamal

Comment: @Mastan - the colons ' indicates string literals, where as the backtick is used to escape any reserved word in mysql.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal , if i don't give that apostrophe then why it work ?

Comment: @Mastan - The apostrophes (colons) '' is wrong with column names, because it indicates string literals not column names, you have to use it with the inserted string literals like this `INSERT INTO Tablename(column1, column2, ...) VALUES('value1', 'value2', ...)`. The backtick however is not mandatory, it is used only to escape reserved words and it is OK to use it for any column names.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO "table_name" ("column1", "column2", ...)
VALUES ("value1", "value2", ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the table name in your SQL query. You need not to put the column names in single quotes. Only non-numeric values need to be place in single quotes.

As you are going with prepared statement then why your not setting the parameters by using `PreparedStatement#setParamater()`.  By this current code I don't think if you taking PreparedStatement's full advantage. Prepared statements have their own set of advantages.
First of all it help to avoid SQL injection and then improves Query performance. You can google the further details.

```
String c = <your_route>;
float d = <your_price>;      
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME('route', 'price') VALUES (?, ?)");
statement.setString(1,c);
statement.setFloat(2,d);
statement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1**

You are missing table name

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tableName ('route', 'price') VALUES ('"+c+"', '"+d+"')");
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

**Point 2**

The way you are dealing with prepared statement is not right way. Always have like below.

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tableName (route, price) VALUES (?, ?)");
statement.setString(1, c);
statement.setFloat(2, d);
```

**Point 3**

Also I think `'route', 'price'` will not work. I feel you wanted to use **`** (backtick) instead of single quote **'**

So, **your final statement should be**

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tableName
(route, price) VALUES (?, ?)");
statement.setString(1, c);
statement.setFloat(2, d);
```